# How to get the path to the requirements file in a Python repo using the GitHub API?

Tags: python, github-api

I am trying to loop through a series of Python repositories and trying to get a link to the `requirements.txt` file in each of them (when present). However, it's not working. It seems I can't even search for a file by name, but only search the code for keywords and restrict the results to results inside files with a given name. I tried to make the search work by sending an empty querystring but it didn't work:

```
https://api.github.com/search/code?q=+repo:<repo name>+filename:requirements.txt
```

Sometimes I don't get results, sometimes I get them but they point to old, outdated code in old commits. I want the current contents from the requirements file so that I can use the `safety` library to see if there are any safety warnings for that repo. Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the contents endpoint on API V3. So in your case, the request would be -

`https://api.github.com/<repo name>/contents/requirements.txt`

eg. To get the file CHANGELOG.md on react.js project the API request would be.

```
https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/contents/CHANGELOG.md
```